# How to use notifyDataSetChanged and setText inside a same onclick method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `setText` a value to a TextView inside `onBindViewHolder`. I tried to use both inside `onClick` method,

```
qtyIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            quantityText.setText("Good");
            toatlPriceText.setText("250");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

My adapter class,

```
public class CartCardviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartCardviewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<CartCardviewModel> dataSet;
private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView itemNameText, itemTypeText, itemDescText, unitPriceText, toatlPriceText, quantityText;
    ImageView itemImage, removeIcon, qtyIncrease, qtyDecrease;

    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.itemNameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name_text);
        this.itemTypeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_type_text);
        this.itemDescText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_desc_text);
        this.unitPriceText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_unit_price_text);
        this.toatlPriceText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_total_price_text);
        this.quantityText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity_text);

        this.itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        this.removeIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_remove_icon);
        this.qtyIncrease = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_quantity_increase);
        this.qtyDecrease = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_quantity_decrease);
    }
}

public CartCardviewAdapter(ArrayList<CartCardviewModel> data) {
    this.dataSet = data;
}

@Override
public CartCardviewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent,
                                                           int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cart_cardview_layout, parent, false);

    CartCardviewAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new CartCardviewAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);

    context = parent.getContext();
    return myViewHolder;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CartCardviewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    shoppingCart = MainActivity.getCartInstance().getCart();

    TextView itemNameText = holder.itemNameText;
    TextView itemTypeText = holder.itemTypeText;
    TextView itemDescText = holder.itemDescText;
    TextView unitPriceText = holder.unitPriceText;
    final TextView toatlPriceText = holder.toatlPriceText;
    final TextView quantityText = holder.quantityText;

    ImageView itemImage = holder.itemImage;
    ImageView removeIcon = holder.removeIcon;
    ImageView qtyIncrease = holder.qtyIncrease;
    ImageView qtyDecrease = holder.qtyDecrease;

    itemNameText.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getItemName());
    itemTypeText.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getItemType());
    itemDescText.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getItemDescription());
    unitPriceText.setText(String.valueOf(dataSet.get(listPosition).getUnitPrice()));
    toatlPriceText.setText(String.valueOf(dataSet.get(listPosition).getTotalPrice()));

    String qty;
    if (dataSet.get(listPosition).getItemQuantity() < 9) {
        qty = "0" + String.valueOf(dataSet.get(listPosition).getItemQuantity());
    } else {
        qty = String.valueOf(dataSet.get(listPosition).getItemQuantity());
    }
    quantityText.setText(qty);

    Picasso.with(context).load(dataSet.get(listPosition).getItemImageUrl()).into(itemImage);

    removeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), String.valueOf(listPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            shoppingCart.removeItem(listPosition);
            dataSet.remove(listPosition);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    qtyIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            shoppingCart.increaseItemQuantity(listPosition);
            quantityText.setText(String.valueOf(shoppingCart.getItemQuantity(listPosition)));
            toatlPriceText.setText(String.valueOf(shoppingCart.getTotalPrice(listPosition)));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    qtyDecrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (shoppingCart.getItemQuantity(listPosition) == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Already Minimum Quantity is Reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                shoppingCart.decreaseItemQuantity(listPosition);
                quantityText.setText(String.valueOf(shoppingCart.getItemQuantity(listPosition)));
                toatlPriceText.setText(String.valueOf(shoppingCart.getTotalPrice(listPosition)));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
}
```

but both don't work at a click. I need to go back and come to see the affected change. I could't understand the problem. Please help me

Comment: you need to change the dataset that you use of adapter. Post your adapter code

Comment: yes post code here

Comment: first , never resort to   notifyDataSetChanged();, its too expensive, notifyItemChanged(position) is cheaper.

Comment: @Raghunandan added

Comment: @Remario added my adapter class

Comment: @ChyperX you set data to text view with dataset list so you need to change that. then refresh with appropriate notify methods on adapter

Comment: @Raghunandan when I log `shoppingCart.getItemQuantity(listPosition))` on next line, It logs correct value. Why couldn't I setText?

Comment: @ChyperX you populate your textview with dataSet. If you change the dataset at a position required and notify the adapter you should see the change

Comment: @ChyperXalso dataset list of type CartCardviewModel. What proprety you want to change in that. likeon button click  `CartCardviewModel cvn = dataSet.get(listPosition)` change the data by calling setter on specific property for example `cvn.setItemQuantity(String.valueOf(shoppingCart.getItemQuantity(listPosition)))` . similarly set total price and then refresh adapter

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks I can fix it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First This line `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)` is for too restrictive, take into consideration lower levels down the line. There are many ways to approach this problem, first you can use a `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` to the recycler hosting the adaptor. Here is a detailed tutorial describing single and long click , [Link](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-recyclerview-implementing-single-item-click-and-long-press-part-ii-b43ef8cb6ad8). Another approach is the interface segration principle.

1. In the adaptor class, create a interface, with one method
2. method signature (View view, int position), depicts a view clicked with repective position in adaptor.
3. Declare a instance of this interface in the adaptor
4. Modify the contructor to accept a interface of that type
5. Let the class with the recylcler view instance implement above interface
6. Pass a new instance to the contructor in the implemented class
7. Then in the overriden method, change your text and call `adaptor.notifyItemChanged(position)`
8. oh, also, in the adaptor class where the views gets init , set onClicklistener with the interface instance.

This tutorial describes exactly the above in great detail,[link](https://piercezaifman.com/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter/).

Your welcome!

Answer (score -2):

the click won't trigger from there , you need to set the click listener of the Image View "qtyIncrease" inside the ViewHolder not in "OnBindViewHolder"

```
  public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView itemNameText, itemTypeText, itemDescText, unitPriceText, toatlPriceText, quantityText;
    ImageView itemImage, removeIcon, qtyIncrease, qtyDecrease;

    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.itemNameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name_text);
        this.itemTypeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_type_text);
        this.itemDescText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_desc_text);
        this.unitPriceText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_unit_price_text);
        this.toatlPriceText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_total_price_text);
        this.quantityText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity_text);

        this.itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        this.removeIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_remove_icon);
        this.qtyIncrease = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_quantity_increase);
        this.qtyDecrease = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_quantity_decrease);


        qtyIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            quantityText.setText("Good");
            toatlPriceText.setText("250");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```